# Django Query or SQL

Tags: sql, django

I have these models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=False)
    text = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
```

and want a Queryset at least with the below fields,

```
author.user.username
text
```

I have read [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) queries but when I try to use that with this view can't get `username` field

```
posts = Post.objects.select_related('person__user')[:10]
```

can I use Django query or have to use SQL raw ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: what is the output you get when you print posts[0].author.user.username?

Comment: It should be `select_related('author__user')` if you want to prefetch the author information, but that alone shouldn't prevent you from doing e.g. `posts[0].author.user.username` as `select_related` is an optimization only.

Comment: oh, sorry! i got the right username!
 but my problem is accessing username after serializing "posts" can u help me with that ? does posts[0].author.user.username hit database again ?

Comment: Look into [Serializing Django objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)

Comment: thank u @Imc ! please answer "does posts[0].author.user.username hit database again ?"

Comment: yes it does, for this part: `posts[0]`, but rest of the part shouldn't hit db again (according to doc)

Comment: so i didn't get my answer, i just want a Query set to convert it to json and send it to client, not a single field that need o(n) query!@ruddra

Comment: This might be useful? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: @DanielBackman error:Cannot resolve keyword 'author.user.username' into field. Choices are: author, text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize like this:

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
json_data = json.dumps(list(Post.objects.values('author__user__username', 'text')[:10]), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

`select_related` should be called with the field names, not the type.

```
posts = Post.objects.select_related('author__user')[:10]  
for post in posts:
    print(post.person.user.username)
    print(post.text)
```

All the `select_related` does is ensure that the foreign fields can be accessed without extra queries (select_related constructs joins to the relevant tables).